# Error SetWindowsHookEx and GetRawInputData

Tags: c++, winapi, event-handling, runtime-error

I have two questions.

First, I wrote a little program to catch all mouse events. I start it in a separate thread, and I get a error which I can not debug:

```cpp
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>


HHOOK hookHandle;

LRESULT CALLBACK callBackHook(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {

    if(nCode == HC_ACTION) {
        std::cout << "Something!" << std::endl;
    }

    return CallNextHookEx(hookHandle, nCode,
                          wParam, lParam);
}

int mouseHook() {


    hookHandle = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL , callBackHook, NULL, 0);

    if(hookHandle == NULL) {
        std::cout << "ERROR CREATING HOOK: ";
        std::cout << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }

    MSG msg;

    while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) != 0) {
        std::cerr << "message!" << std::endl;
    }

    UnhookWindowsHookEx(hookHandle);

    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::thread mouse(mouseHook);
    return 0;
}
```

Error Message (the german buttons say "Cancel", "Retry", "Ignore"):

[image]

Second, is it possible to get the raw data input from `lParam` of the `callBackHook` function? I don't know how to register an input device without an `HWND`.

Comment: Do you still get the error if you get rid of the `cout`/`cerr` statements? Try using `OutputDebugString()` instead. As for the `lParam`, a `WH_MOUSE_LL` callback receives a `MSLLHOOKSTRUCT*` pointer in the `lParam`, so the only data you can access is what the [`MSLLHOOKSTRUCT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-msllhookstruct) struct provides. The Raw Input API requires an `HWND` to deliver `WM_INPUT` messages to, that is the only way you can access the raw input data.

Comment: You need to wait for the thread to end (use `mouse.join()`). The main process will directly return 0 after you create the thread, causing the thread to get this error.

Comment: *I don't know how to register an input device without an HWND*, you could create a [Message-Only Window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-features#message-only-windows)

Comment: There are instructions on the dialog. It says: *"Press Retry to debug the application"*. That takes you right to the faulting operation in the debugger. Make sure you understand `std::thread`'s rules with respect to [destruction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/~thread). If you don't want to get into that, use a [std::jthread](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/jthread) instead. That requires a C++ compiler supporting C++20.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you needs to wait the thread exit, use `mouse.join()`. If the main process returns directly, the thread it owns will also be terminated, which will cause this issue.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::thread mouse(mouseHook);
    mouse.join();
    return 0;
}
```

Second,

> I don't know how to register an input device without an HWND

Don't worry, you could create a [Message-Only Window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-features#message-only-windows) for that.

Sample (remove some error checking):

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
LRESULT CALLBACK WindProc(HWND hWnd, UINT Msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (Msg == WM_INPUT)
    {
        cout << "Something!" << endl;
        HRAWINPUT hRawInput = (HRAWINPUT)lParam;
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, Msg, wParam, lParam);
}

int main()
{
    WNDCLASSEX wcx = { 0 };
    wcx.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wcx.lpfnWndProc = WindProc;
    wcx.hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
    wcx.lpszClassName = TEXT("RawInputClass");
    RegisterClassEx(&wcx);
    HWND hWnd = CreateWindowEx(0, TEXT("RawInputClass"), NULL, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, HWND_MESSAGE, NULL, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);

    RAWINPUTDEVICE rid = { 0 };
    rid.usUsagePage = 0x01;
    rid.usUsage = 0x02; //mouse
    rid.dwFlags = RIDEV_INPUTSINK;
    rid.hwndTarget = hWnd;

    RegisterRawInputDevices(&rid, 1, sizeof(RAWINPUTDEVICE));

    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't produce valuable error diagnostics. There is a very narrow window in which `GetLastError` returns meaningful results. Your call is *way* outside that window.